# Change dtype of specific columns with iloc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to change the dtype of some columns in my DataFrame via iloc. But when I try this the dtype does not change (it's still object):

```
import pandas as pd
names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'class']
df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv', names=names, header=None)
df = df[1:]

In [11]: df.head()
Out[11]:
   sepal-length  sepal-width  petal-length  petal-width   class
1           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
3           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
4           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
5           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa


In [12]: df.iloc[:,:-1] = df.iloc[:,:-1].astype(float)
# No Error

In [13]: df.dtypes  # still object dtype
Out[13]:
sepal-length    object
sepal-width     object
petal-length    object
petal-width     object
class           object
dtype: object
```

Note: I can do this without iloc, but it's too long:

```
df[['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width']] = df[['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width']].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`infer_objects`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html):

```
In [11]: df.infer_objects()
Out[11]:
   sepal-length  sepal-width  petal-length  petal-width   class
1           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
3           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
4           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
5           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa

In [12]: df.infer_objects().dtypes
Out[12]:
sepal-length    float64
sepal-width     float64
petal-length    float64
petal-width     float64
class            object
dtype: object
```

---

The issue is that whilst the right-hand-side is correct:

```
In [21]: df.iloc[:,:-1].astype(float).dtypes
Out[21]:
sepal-length    float64
sepal-width     float64
petal-length    float64
petal-width     float64
dtype: object
```

The assignment `df.iloc[:,:-1] =` is updating existing columns and *not* changing their dtype.

Comment: The __infer_objects__ method is available since pandas 0.21, so if you are using a previous release you have to upgrade pandas first.

Comment: @MiltonArangoG good point, actually I hadn't seen it before (last I had seen was that convert_objects was deprecated :) so I am glad it is replaced)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with using `iloc`. You can get around this using regular column indexing:

```
df[df.columns[:-1]] = df[df.columns[:-1]].astype(float)
```

Alternatively:

You can apply `to_numeric` to all columns like this, and it will skip `class` because it can't be converted:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.infer_objects()` is the right way to prepare a df for machine learning algorithms (like XGBoost). Most csv imported dataframes have 'object' dtypes and they are not supported by many machine learning algorithms like catboost, xgboost, etc... To get them working use `df.infer_objects()`.